# How does Google save changes done on a Google document?

Tags: python

I was wondering how does Google save the changes made to a Google document on the fly. Obviously it cannot send all the contents of the document being edited on keyup. I had left Firebug open and it seems like on keyup a text range along with whats changed in that range is being sent. Though I m not sure of this. Any idea how this is being done?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but this looks to be the most information Google gives on the auto-save. http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=44665&topic=15119

Comment: Maybe it sends a `diff`-like patch? I have no idea.

Comment: It knows which cell you just edited, I assume it either sends an update when a "dirty" (modified) cell loses focus or else keeps a list of dirty cells and sends them when you pause for a moment. This won't be a lot of data.

Comment: If you want to dig into this, you might want to have a look at the (protocol)[http://www.waveprotocol.org/] for Google wave, and the open-sourced (code)[https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/wave/trunk/]. It might not be the same as Google docs, but it's designed to do something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Operational Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) is the core idea behind by many collaborative real-time editors.  [Google Wave Operational Transformation](http://wave-protocol.googlecode.com/hg/whitepapers/operational-transform/operational-transform.html) documents the protocol in Google Wave, and I'd assume that Google Docs is similar.